# Parsing comments and strings in source code

Tags: regex, parsing, tags, token, tokenize

I'm designing and implementing a scripting language, and for the "reading" stage I'm taking the time-tested and straightforward approach of splitting the code up into tokens (lexical analysis) followed by using a stack-based AST generator to squeeze syntactic structure out of the token stream (parsing). However, I'm facing an issue with strings, comments, and how they interact.

(for reference, code in my language uses `~` to start comments)

This might be the wrong approach, but I'm performing the lexical analysis step using regular expressions.  For `n` kinds of tokens, I run `n` tokenization passes on my code, with each pass finding substrings that match the given regex and "tagging" them, until eventually every character is tagged.  Each regex ignores matches that lie within already-tagged sections of source, only tagging unclaimed land.  This is useful, because you wouldn't want, for example, a `number` token infiltrating a token like `translate3d`.

The issue I'm running into is with comments embedded in strings and strings embedded in comments.  I don't know how to simultaneously make this

```
"The ~ is my favorite character!  It's so happy-looking!"
```

be tagged as a string, and have this

```
~ "handles" the Exception (just logs it to a file nobody ever reads and moves on)
```

be tagged as a comment.  It seems that either way, you have to impose some ordering on the passes of lexical analysis, and that either the comment or the string pass is going to "win" and tag a substring it has no business tokenizing.  For example, either the string is tagged like so: (I'm using XML notation because it's a good way to represent tagged regions of text.  XML is not actually used in my program at any point)

```
"The <comment>~ is my favorite character!  It's so happy-looking!"</comment>
```

or the comment is tagged like this:

```
<comment>~ </comment><string>"handles"</string>the Exception (just logs it to a file and moves on)
```

Either it's assumed a string starts in the middle of a comment or a comment starts in the middle of a string.

What's odd is that it seems that this system of regex passes tagging substrings is *exactly* what the syntax highlighting on a text editor does, and comments and strings work fine there.  I've already developed the textmate/submlime text 2 syntax definition for my language, and all I had to do was (in a simplified version of the actual format used)

```
<syntax>
    <color>
        string_color
    </color>
    <pattern>
        "[^"]*"
    </pattern>
</syntax>
<syntax>
    <color>
        comment_color
    </color>
    <pattern>
        ~.*
    </pattern>
</syntax>
```

Everything works fine when I'm writing sample code.  When I tried to emulate what I imagine the behavior of the text editor is, however, I ran into the problems mentioned above.  How can this be fixed, preferably in the most elegant way possible?  Obviously, special handling could be added, stripping all the comments off the source code before any lexical analysis is done, except for comments inside strings (which requires the reader (reader in this case being the machine, not the human) to detect what sections of code are strings *twice*), but I'm sure there must be a better way, simply because sublime text only has knowledge of the regexes used to specify the two kinds of regions of code, and with only that information it behaves exactly as expected.

Comment: I wish I could help. Out of curiosity, is this a new language we'll get to play with at some point? :-) Good luck by the way

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement!  Hopefully you'll get to play with it.  It's pretty experimental, which if you're a language geek should sound juicy and delicious.  Filled to the brim with weird features.  Spaces are allowed in identifiers, every function is multiple-dispatch, all control flow is done with function calls and blocks (like smalltalk), symbol tables are first-class values, and assignment is done with a function.  It's designed to give you insane amounts of power while remaining predictable and modular, so, for example, you can redefine `/` for integers, but only locally.

Comment: For the record, it's going to be called "Royale".  Check back in a month or two - I think you'll find it pretty interesting!

Comment: It does sound really cool. I'd love to try it.

Comment: Why aren't you using a standard lexing tool such as Flex?  It also uses regexes, but everything happens in one pass, and since each token is unambiguously determined, you don't get token-confusion such as you have.

Comment: Maybe I'm a victim of the ["not invented here"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NotInventedHere) philosophy, but I like building my own tools when I can.  It's a neat learning experience.  Second of all, I'm writing in D, and I'm not sure if there are any lexing tools that interoperate with D.  Finally, I don't like the regex sub-language, so I'm writing my regexes as objects which compile themselves to regexs (think `new Optional(new Either(new Literal("x"), new Literal("y")))` rather than `(?:x|y)?`.  I know it's more verbose, but it's a million times clearer IMHO.  Also, it handles escaping for you.

Comment: The regex engine moves from left to right in the string. If a `~` comes first it's a comment until a newline appears, and if a `"` comes first it's a string until a closing `"` appears. I can't see what the problem is. Oh, I see, it's because on each pass you're only looking for one type. The solution is to tag both comments and strings on the same pass.

Comment: The problem is that it's done it two passes.  I suppose I could roll up all my tokens into one mega-regex like `(pattern_for_comment|pattern_for_string|pattern_for_symbol|pattern_for_number)`

Comment: Yes, that would avoid the problem, and also be more efficient. Good luck.

Comment: However, I'm not sure how I'd recover the information as to what kind of token each capture was.  Do most regex engines give you the ability to "tag" captures so you know what branch of the `(a|b|c|d)` it matched?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28238/discussion-between-selectricsimian-and-mikem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than first tagging the source code before tokenizing it, and using several passes to do so, I recommend that you abandon the tagging and just tokenize the code in one pass using one regular expression.

If you construct an all-encompassing regex that contains sub-patterns to match and capture each token, you can then match globally and determine the token type by examining the capture group contents.

In simple example, if you had a regex such as

```
"([^"]*)"|~([^\n]*)|(\d+(?:.\d+)?)
```

to match either strings, comments, or numbers, then if a string was matched the first capture group `()` would contain it, and all the other capture groups would be empty.

So, in your `for each` loop ([D Language Regular expressons](http://dlang.org/regular-expression.html)) you would use conditional statements and the match object's capture group contents to determine the next token to be added.

And you wouldn't necessarily have to use just one large regex, you could match several token types in one capture group and then within the `for each` block apply a further regex (or `indexOf` etc.) on the capture group contents to determine the token.

Comment: Normally, you have separate regular expressions, one per type of token (for example, one for strings, one for comments, one for numbers, one for identifiers).  Then you can classify the different types of matched object more simply in the scanner.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! However, as an inevitable side effect of having a regex longer than 10 characters, now I have two problems: `(?:(~(?:.)*)|("(?:[^"])*")|((?:\d)+(?:.(?:\d)+)?)|((?:[a-z]|[A-Z])(?:(?: |\w)*\w)?:)|((?:[a-z]|[A-Z])(?:(?: |\w)*\w)?!)|((?:[a-z]|[A-Z])(?:(?: |\w)*\w)?)|(:(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])(?:(?: |\w)*\w)?)|('(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])(?:(?: |\w)*\w)?)|(#)|(,(?:(?: | )+\n)?)|((?:;|\n))|((?:\+|-|\*|/|\*\*|=|=/=|>|<|<=|>=|@))|((?:\(|\)))|((?:\{|\}))|((?:\[|\]))|((?: | )+))`  Hmmm...

Comment: @SelectricSimian. Don't be afraid of longer regex - they can be thousands of characters long! Alternatively, you could follow the approach mentioned by J. Leffler above, and iterate through the string applying separate regex at each position as you do so. It's the same difference really, but avoids the need for a long regex.

Comment: @SelectricSimian. Also, your regex looks like it could be shortened considerably.

Comment: The regex is somewhat auto-generated actually - I've set up a little library so that I can write the regex as structured data which compiles down into regex source.  Makes things a lot easier to read and work with, although a lot more verbose, since x? becomes new Optional(new Literal("x")) and so on.  What's neat is that, before the translation step, you can traverse the regex as a data structure, determining how many captures are in it, dynamically `|`-ing to regexes together, etc.  So I write the patterns separately and a function combines them, as well as handles the capture-checking.